# Работа со строками в С++

Tags: строки, c++

```
char str[] = "asdf";

cout << str << endl;

*str = "qwer"[2];

cout << str << endl;

*(str+2) = "qwer"[1];

cout << str << endl;
```

Выводит соответственно

`asdf
esdf
eswf`

Волнует место `*str = "qwer"[2];` как эта конструкция работает? К какому типу приводится строка в кавычках - к `char*` или к `string`?

Comment: а это классический с++ или .NET c++ (CLI)??? а то это все может сильно поменять.

Comment: И в самом деле в g++ никак не компилится. @pol, чем пользовались ?

Comment: К char. Но str - это указатель, а вы в него пишите значение char. Аяяя...
Поищите в моем блоге статьи на эту тему. Ссылка в профиле.

Comment: @Jakeroid там неправильно вставилось... исправил.

Comment: @KoVadim и @avp компилится в gcc - тут только хешкод поел указатели перед str, наверно из-за этого и не компилится у вас)

Comment: Теперь (со звездочками) все понятно.

Comment: Строка в кавычках естественно char *. 

У Вас в программе string вообще нет, почему бы строковая константа приводилась к string при извлечении из нее элемента ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"something"  -  это строковый литерал. Он имеет тип `const char*` - константный указатель на облать памяти где хранится эта строка. Индексация в этой строке такая же как в обычном С-массиве, завершается она нулевым символом.

**UPD**:
Извиняюсь, невнимательно прочитал вопроc.
Такая конструкция не работает, т.к. str имеет тип массив char-ов размера 5 и изменить его **нельзя**.
Тем более присваивая к `char`-у. KoVadim правильно написал, но его заминусовали почему-то.

Comment: @dzhioev идеально все работает)

Answer (score 2):

эта конструкция не работает и не должна компилироватся. 
`str = "qwer"[2];` - это попытка указателю на массив символов присвоить символ...
gcc ругается на такое очень сильно `(incompatible types in assignment of 'const char' to 'char [5]')`

Answer (score 1):

autoboxing к `char`'y

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "qwer"[2];
```

Здесь у вас `str` - указатель на `char`(`char *`), при этом она указывает на 0-ю позицию, созданого Вами массива. `"qwer"[2]` - берет `char` (константный, `const_char`), и присваивает его значению по аддресу str, то есть, элементу на 0-й позиции.

Answer (score 0):

*str* - это указатель на первый элемент массива. То есть * *str* - непосредственно сам первый элемент. *"qwer"* - константный массив. Написав **str = "qwer"[2] *- вы "говорите" компилятору, что нужно взять элемент типа* char *из константного массива* "qwer"* под номером 3(потому что первый элемент с номером ноль, а третий с индексом 0 + 2) и поместить в** str*, то есть в первый элемент массива* str*. 
Почему именно с нуля? Индекс массива  - это смещение указателя от заданной позиции. То есть переменная массива - указатель на первый элемент, а индекс смещение.